# React UseEffect Throwing error in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

I have a pnpm monorepo project that uses shared components. I have a top level BrowserRouter component that all of my components fall under. One of my components has a `const navigate = useNavigate();` within it, that works perfectly as expected when running my project locally(vite), but when deployed to production(have tested with vercel and netlify and both show the same behaviour) my useNavigate throws an error. Unfortunately, when logging the error it only logs as "Error"(have tried with e.name and e.message both). I know a very common cause of useNavigate errors is when a useNavigate is used outside of a Router component, but I know for sure mine is in one, i see it in my code as well as in the components tab in the react dev tools in chrome.

My monorepo can be found here: https://github.com/ClydeFrog04/portfolio-monorepo/

Relevant files are packages/portfolio/src/App.tsx, and the `Calculatorinator` Route, which uses the Calculatorinator.tsx component.
The packages/portfolio/main.tsx is where my BrowserRouter wraps the project.

A stripped down look at the project structure is:

main.tsx

```
    root.render(
        <StrictMode>
            <Router>
                <RootProvider>
                    <App/>
                </RootProvider>
            </Router>
        </StrictMode>
    );
```

App.tsx

```
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route
              path={"calculatorinator"}
              element={
                <div className="calculatorinatorContainer">
                  <Calculatorinator/>
                </div>
              }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
```

and Calculatorinator.tsx

```
    const Calculatorinator = (props: CalculatorinatorProps) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    ...
    }
```

I have tested adding a router to the Calculatorinator:main.tsx file, which i expect *not* to fix the issue, since the component is imported into another project, thought i'd try it anyway.
`your text`
I tried adding a SrictMode wrapper in main.tsx, I saw another stack overflow that suggested that may work, it did not.

I also have a _redirects file in my portfolio project, this fixed an issue earlier in development that allowed refresh on the routes to work as expected. My _redirects file has one entry `/*  /index.html  200` to redirect routes back to the portfolio index.html, i also saw someone suggest adding one of these files, but i already had it /:

you can see a deploy preview here: https://deploy-preview-4--phenomenal-shortbread-4b1baf.netlify.app/
and click on the calculator button to see the error, inspect to see logs. This error is *not* producible when i run my project locally via `vite` command, only seems to be a problem on production deploys.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the error occurring when you click on a component that uses `useNavigate` or is the error occurring at build time?

Comment: The error occurs when I click on the Calculatorinator component that uses the `useNavigate`, and once that component rendered, it happens on all renders so if you refresh the page, error. basically no error when navigated to `/` but we do get the error on `/calculator/`

Comment: What exactly is the error being thrown? What are the reproduction steps? You haven't really provided helpful details. Can you [edit] to include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited to include what I can, the error only logs as "Error" which has been very un-helpful /: Please let me know if i can include any other info <3

Comment: What if you *don't* try to catch this error and just let it happen?

Comment: You mention monorepos... what is the "main" repo or app code? This might be an issue where you've multiple `react-router-dom` instances. It should be a dependency in one repo, and a peer-dependency in the others.

Comment: removing the try catch prevents the page from rendering entirely, and still logs errors in the console /:

The "main" repo is the portfolio repo. i can remove the one react-router-dom instance in the calculator project(though it shouldn't even be running) but i did have that not there earlier and i was still getting this issue.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by passing the navigate function to my calculator component from the top level react app. I am still not sure why all of a sudden the navigate stopped working, so i don't think this "answers" my question, but my app is working again.